# Increase speed of PHP and MySQL webservice

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created a web service using php and mysql to insert and return data for my app.  One of the main complaints from users is the response is too slow, which I agree, as it takes anywhere from 5-10 seconds to complete task.  Originally thought it was a hosting performance issue, but has not made a difference (godaddy versus AWS).

Looking at the SQL code in my php files, I think that is the issue.  I'm looking to re-write to increase speed.  I believe the issue is I use timestamps, and to return I always look for the max(timestamp).

Here is my input SQL statement:

```
 $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO meals (user, date, meal, timeStamp, food) VALUES ('$user','$date','$meal','$timeStamp','$food')");
```

Here is my return SQL statement:

```
 $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM meals WHERE user = '$user' AND date = '$date' AND meal = '$meal' AND timeStamp = (SELECT MAX(`timeStamp`)FROM meals WHERE user = '$user' AND date = '$date' AND meal = '$meal')");
```

Would I be better off using an UPDATE or similar instead of using timestamps?  Any other recommendations?

Comment: Have you profiled your API to be sure these queries are the problem? Use `microtime` to find out how long everything takes.

Comment: What indexes do you have on your meals table?

Comment: And why can't you `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY timestamp` rather than using that insanely inefficient `AND timeStamp = (SELECT MAX(`timeStamp`)FROM meals WHERE ...`

Comment: Whether or not you use insert or update depends on whether you want to keep a record of previous meals.  If you do decide to go with updates, you'll need some conditional logic to see if there is anything to update.

Comment: You can also speed up production with query paramters and stored procedures.

Comment: There is no need to keep record of previous meals for same day & meal #.  I have an auto-increment index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM meals
WHERE user = '$user' AND date = '$date' AND meal = '$meal' AND
      timeStamp = (SELECT MAX(`timeStamp`)
                   FROM meals
                   WHERE user = '$user' AND date = '$date' AND meal = '$meal'
                  );
```

Assuming that you want only one row, the first simplification is:

```
SELECT *
FROM meals
WHERE user = '$user' AND date = '$date' AND meal = '$meal'
ORDER BY timestamp desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Next, indexes will help this query.  In fact, an index on `meals(user, date, meal, timestamp)` would work for both the `where` and the `order by`.  That should improve performance.

Comment: Doesn't timestamp need to be the leftmost indexed column to be used by the order by clause?

Comment: @AlixAxel . . . Not in this case.  It needs to be the leftmost column after the equality columns used in the `where` clause.  This is explained here (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Comment: @Bachzen . . . I don't understand your question.  Adding the index should actually improve your query as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what I meant is the query is still using a timestamp, which will add to table size, would it be more efficient to update (override) existing instead?

Comment: If the only reason you have the timestamp field is to get the most recent record, you don't need it.  You can order by the PK field which you have said is autoincrement.

Comment: @Bachzen . . . I wouldn't worry about such a minor performance improvement unless you have tens or hundreds of millions of rows in your table.

Comment: @ Dan Bracuk - wouldn't ordering by PK field or timestamp accomplish the same thing with similar speed?

Comment: @Bachzen . . . Assuming the primary key is an auto-incremented column that correlates with the timestamp, you can use it.  You could have a situation where some rows were "missed" and need to be re-inserted at a later date.  This could break the relationship between the primary key and timestamp.